# Copyright text in asp.net view pages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Folks,
 Looking for help from the community.

I have to add  copyright text in all aspx/ascx/master pages on the top.

The sample copyright text is as follows -

```
 <!-- © 2014 xyz company    .. .. . .. ........ ........
  .............................
 -->
```

This copyright text needs to be added as comment on the file.
When I try to add this copyright text using  powershell/macro, my page encoding gets changed to ANSI. Which intern will trouble or say troubles while merging/checking-in the file. The issue is  '©' character.

```
    Option Strict Off
    Option Explicit Off
    Imports System
    Imports EnvDTE
    Imports EnvDTE80
    Imports EnvDTE90
    Imports EnvDTE90a
    Imports EnvDTE100
    Imports System.Diagnostics

    Public Module RecordingModule


        Sub IterateFiles()
            Dim solution As Solution =

 DTE.Solution
        For Each prj As Project In solution.Projects
            IterateProjectFiles(prj.ProjectItems)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub IterateProjectFiles(ByVal prjItms As ProjectItems)
        For Each file As ProjectItem In prjItms
            If file.SubProject IsNot Nothing Then
                AddHeaderToItem(file)
                IterateProjectFiles(file.ProjectItems)
            ElseIf file.ProjectItems IsNot Nothing AndAlso file.ProjectItems.Count > 0 Then
                AddHeaderToItem(file)
                IterateProjectFiles(file.ProjectItems)
            Else
                AddHeaderToItem(file)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddHeaderToItem(ByVal file As ProjectItem)
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("view.SolutionExplorer")
        If file.Name.EndsWith(".aspx") OrElse file.Name.EndsWith(".ascx") OrElse file.Name.EndsWith(".Master") Then
            file.Open()
            file.Document.Activate()

            AddHeader()

            file.Document.Save()
            file.Document.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddHeader()
        Dim cmtHeader As String = "<!--  "
        Dim cmtCopyright As String = "Copyright © 2014 xyz company"
        Dim cmtFooter As String = "  -->"

        Dim cmt = "//"

        DTE.UndoContext.Open("Header Comment")
        Dim ts As TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection, TextSelection)
        ts.StartOfDocument()
        ts.Text = String.Format(cmtHeader, cmt)
        ts.NewLine()
        ts.Text = String.Format(cmtCopyright)
        ts.NewLine()
        ts.Text = String.Format(cmtFooter)
        ts.NewLine()
        DTE.UndoContext.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Above please file macro code above.

Adding to this, these files have different character encoding - **utf-8** and **utf-8 with BOM**.  So I should be able to retain the encoding too.

Please let me know you need more information.

Comment: Can you share your macro? And why not use `&copy;`,  which would be the proper encoding.

Comment: Why would you add them to ASPX pages? The master pages get combined with the ASPX when presented to the client. Manually add it to your master pages and you're done. Seems like using PowerShell or a Macro is overkill for what you need to accomplish.

Comment: @mason Every view page needs to have this copyright comment. That's why to add this as comment I need to use powershell/macro to add this in all the files.

Comment: You're missing my point. ASPX pages get combined with the master page when they're presented to the client. Therefore, you don't need to add it to all ASPX pages, just the top level master pages and any ASPX pages that don't have a master page.

Comment: @mason ok. Let's say I agree. But the issue still persists, it changes the encoding to ANSI in master page. Any help here?

Comment: @jessehouwing updated question with macro code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like issue is ©. So I will have to replace this with (c). This is tested OK.